# What happens to the birds when a demon slayer dies?

Tags: demon-slayer

What happens to the birds when a demon slayer dies? Do they go into retirement? Do they go to someone new?

I haven't read the manga but I don't mind spoilers if they help answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the manga either, but from my point of view
The bird is just a messenger assigned by the HQ to a demon slayer so, the will probably get transferred to a new slayer if the existing keeper dies.